# Using libvirt with Qemu and cannot load kernel?

Tags: linux, qemu

I am editing the relevant VM's XML file with the following parameters:

```
  <kernel>../Downloads/linux-5.19.8/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage</kernel>
  <initrd>../obj/initramfs-busybox-x86.cpio.gz</initrd>
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
error: Failed to start domain 'A'
error: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: qemu: could not open kernel file '../Downloads/linux-5.19.8/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage': Permission denied
```

How could this be? I am running as sudo.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

First: I'm suspicious of the use of relative paths (`../Downloads`) in the XML file; those might be interpreted relative to the cwd for `libvirtd`, rather than *your* cwd. I would replace those with fully qualified paths.

Second: It is likely that your virtual machines are running as a non-root user (for example, on my Fedora system, virtual machines run as the `qemu` user). When you're referring to items in your home directory, you have to ensure that (a) the files themselves are readable by the appropriate user, and that (b) the user at least has search (`+x`) permissions on any intervening directories.